# Test-Path -Path behaviour with array of paths

Tags: powershell, path, boolean, file-exists

I'm trying to check if multiple files/folders exist. The `Test-Path` parameter `-Path` accepts a `[string[]]` array. Please see example code:

```
$arr = @(
    "C:\a\fake\path\test1.txt",
    "C:\another\fake\path\test2.txt",
    "C:\not\a\path\test3.txt",
    "Z:\not\a\path"
)
if (Test-Path -Path $arr) {
    $true
} else {
    $false
}
```

Output: `$true`

None of the paths in `$arr` are valid. They do not exist (I don't have a `Z:` drive) -- what is happening here?

Comment: An array with 2 or more elements when coerced to boolean is `$true` doesnt matter what its elements are. What exactly are you expecting from your code?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I want to use `Test-Path -Path` and pass an array of paths. It seems it does not support that, or I have misunderstood..

Comment: fwiw, in most cases you are better of _skipping the check_ if the file exists. Instead, attempt to open or create the directly using the appropriate file access or file share modes. Then handle the error if the task fails.

Comment: Passing multiple paths as arguments is supported, remove your if condition and you will see that the cmdlet will output 4 times `$false`, so you need to be mote specific on what exactly you're expecting from your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the helpful comments:

[`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) *does* support passing an *array* of paths (both by *argument* and *via the pipeline*, but it outputs a Boolean value (`$true` or `$false`) indicating the existence of a path *for each input path*.

- That is, with 4 input paths, as in your example, you'll get *4 Boolean output values*.
- Coercing an array with *two ore more* elements - irrespective of the type of its elements - to a *single* Boolean, such as in the context of an [`if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_If) statement's conditional, *always yields `$true`*; e.g.:

  ```bash
  [bool] @($false, $false) # -> !! $true
  ```

  - (By contrast, a *single-element* array is coerced the same way as its single element itself, so that `[bool] @($false)` is effectively the same as `[bool] $false` and therefore `$false`).
  - See the conceptual [about_Booleans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Booleans) help topic for more information.

---

If you want to know if *at least one* of the input paths *doesn't* exist, use the [`-contains` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains):

```bash
if ((Test-Path -Path $arr) -contains $false) {
  "At least one of the input paths doesn't exist."
}
```

(Conversely, `-contains $true` tells if you at least one path *exists*.)